# storing large data in string

Tags: c#

i am trying to store large data more than 255 characters in a string datatype but it truncates after 255. how can i achive this basically i need to pass this data to database

Answer (score 6):

C# strings do not have any particular character limit.  However the database column you are writing to may have a limit.  If you are storing large amounts of data, you should use a BLOB column instead of an ordinary varchar type.

Comment: but when i am reading it from excel and trying to write it to xml only 255 characters are written in xml

Comment: How much do you READ from excel there? Could it be that this is an excel per cell limit?

Comment: actually i am reading it from Excel text box shape control
Worksheet.Shapes.Item("Shape1").TextFrame.Characters(1,Type.Missing).Text

Comment: Couldn't you post the complete details of your exact problem above? pretty vague question!

Answer (score 4):

[StringBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Like they said the string class is not limited, but you can do this for large strings. I feel it handles them better.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Some text...");
sb.append("more text...");
sb.append("even more text!");
sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, it sounds like you have several different technologies involved - Excel, XML, databases etc. Try to tackle just one at a time. First read the data out of Excel, and make sure you can do that without any truncation.

Write a small console app which will read the value, then write it to the console - and its length. If that works, you know the problem isn't in Excel.

Next you can write a small console app with hardcoded input data (so you don't need to keep using interop with Excel) and write the XML from that, or whatever your next stage is.

Basically, take the one big problem ("when I read data from Excel and write it to the database it truncates long values") and split it into smaller and smaller ones until you've found what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The string type does not limit strings to 255 characters. Your database column must be 255 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I know that c# strings can hold much longer data than that. If the truncation occurs on commiting to DB, check the length constraint on ur Db field

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the Excel part; `.Character` has a 255 characters limitation.

To read the complete text from a shape the following VBA syntax would do:

```
Worksheets("YourSheet").Shapes("Shape1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```